# How to split a hash into multiple arrays of keys based the values not exceeding a certain sum in each array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a large hash, where the keys are names, like "Alex", and the values are numeric, like "100".
How can I split this hash into multiple arrays that contain the keys, of which the sum of values doesn't exceed a certain threshold value?

**Example**

I have the hash

```
{"Alex"=>50, "Bamby"=>100, "Jordan"=>300, "Ger"=>700, "Aus"=>500, "Can"=>360}
```

and I want to split it into packs of 1000 from the beginning (doesn't have to be from the beginning but would be nice),
meaning:

```
array1 = ["Alex", "Bamby", "Jordan"] # not "Ger" bc it would exceed the 1000 in sum

array2 = ["Ger"] # not the Aus because it again would exceed the 1000

array3 = ["Aus", "Can"]
```

---

The best solution would actually be to have it optimized in a way that the code makes arrays all close or equal 1000 but that's the next step I guess...

Thank you so much in advance! ~Alex

Comment: see [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) for one approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
h = {"Alex"=>50, "Bamby"=>100, "Jordan"=>300, "Ger"=>700, "Aus"=>500, "Can"=>360}

tot = 0
h.keys.slice_before { |k| (tot += h[k]) > 1000 ? tot = h[k] : false }.to_a
  #=> [["Alex", "Bamby", "Jordan"], ["Ger"], ["Aus", "Can"]]
```

Not that if `tot > 1000` the block returns a truthy value (`h[k]`) and the parentheses around `tot += h[k]` are necessary.

See [Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the elements inside the hash like this, the explain is in the comments:

```
hash={"Alex"=>50, "Bamby"=>100, "Jordan"=>300, "Ger"=>700, "Aus"=>500, "Can"=>360}
rs = [] # the outside array
rss = [] # the array inside the array
m = 0 # check if the sum of nexts are 1000
hash.each do |key, n|
  if m+n <= 1000  # if the counter + the next element < 1000
    m += n # then add it to the counter
    rss << key # add the key to the actual array
  else
    rs << rss #else m is equal or bigger than 1000, so, I add all the keys to the main array
    m=n # the element that overcomes m to 1000, becomes the first count now
    rss=[key] # And that key is the first element of a new array
  end
end
rs << rss #Importan! at the end, the final array need to be added outside the loop

print rs
```

Result _

```
=> [["Alex", "Bamby", "Jordan"], ["Ger"], ["Aus", "Can"]]
```

Comment: It seems like you're using comments to explain your code in its entirety. Better to write an explanation before or after your code, with a few comments where appropriate.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 thanks for the comment, I will do that next time, I found it clear so you can see exactly the line I'm talking about, but yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

```
original = {"Alex"=>50, "Bamby"=>100, "Jordan"=>300, "Ger"=>700, "Aus"=>500, "Can"=>360}

chunked = original.inject([]) do |array, (key, value)|
  array << {} unless array.any?

  if array.last.values.sum + value <= 1_000
    array.last.merge!(key => value)
  else
    array << { key => value }
  end

  array
end

# => [{"Alex"=>50, "Bamby"=>100, "Jordan"=>300}, {"Ger"=>700}, {"Aus"=>500, "Can"=>360}]
```

Comment: How about using `Enumerable#chunk_while`? I say this because I notice your variable `chunked`.

Comment: Because I felt hashes were a more ergonomic output in this case.